# htaccess redirect with ( sign

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this link

```
/Kurs-og-konferanser/Inspirasjon-og-motivasjon/Kvinner-i-tiden/Talere-i-Oslo-31.-mai/(event)/1247843
```

Which I want to redirect to

```
alle-kurs-og-konferanser/kvinner-i-tiden
```

So add this to my .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /Kurs-og-konferanser/Inspirasjon-og-motivasjon/Kvinner-i-tiden/Talere-i-Oslo-31.-mai/(event)/1247843 http://{url}/alle-kurs-og-konferanser/kvinner-i-tiden
```

If I just add this to my .htaccess file it redirects to

```
alle-kurs-og-konferanser/kvinner-i-tiden/Talere-i-Oslo-31.-mai/(event)/1247843
```

So my guess its something with (event) so how do I escape this - I have already tried with (event) but this just add some extra slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

> Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the target URL.

If you don't want the additional path information, don't use `Redirect`. Use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead. You will need to express the URI you are matching against as a regular expression, this includes anchoring it to the start of the string (`^`) and escaping any characters that are regular expression metacharacters.

Comment: Changed everything to RedirectMatch with both ^ and $ and escaped the (xxx) with \\(xxx\\) and now it works perfect.